# What is the difference between set parameter and set attribute in liferay 6.2?

Tags: liferay, portlet

I am pretty much confused what to be used when, 
and  what is the advantages and disadvantages of using these parameters.

Can anyone help me out to get the clarification in this?

Comment: Liferay 2 was released 13 years ago !!!
Do you really mean Liferay 2 or Portlet 2.0 spec?

Comment: sorry its liferay6.2

Comment: Please clarify which setParameter and setAttribute you refer to!

Comment: actionrequest.setParameter() and actionrequest.setattribute()

Answer (score 5):

So your question is

#### What is the difference between `actionRequest.setParameter(...)` and `actionRequest.setAttribute(...)` in Liferay 6.2 ?

This question is still stated wrong for 2 reasons

1. [ActionRequest](https://docs.liferay.com/portlet-api/2.0/javadocs/javax/portlet/ActionRequest.html) is not a Liferay specific thing. It's part of portlet API that any portal needs to implement.
2. There is no `setParameter(...)`method in [ActionRequest](https://docs.liferay.com/portlet-api/2.0/javadocs/javax/portlet/ActionRequest.html)

I assume what you intended to ask is

#### What is the difference between parameters and attributes in the context of portal API?

- **parameters** are the things sent to the portlet by the client. They typically come as part of the URL (after the ? sign in case of GET HTTP method) or included in the HTTP request (in case of POST HTTP method). You would use `getParameter(...)` method in your portlet to read the value of a paramter sent to the portlet by the client. There is no sense to have `setParameter(...)` method as your portlet is the final recipient of those parameters.
- **attributes** are your way to store and read data in the context of the current action request. If your portlet calls other clasess it can prepare some data for them and store it in the request scope via `setAttribute(...)` method. Thise classes can later on read that data via `getAttribute(...)` and store data on their own to be later one read by the portlet. Once the request is processed the request scope is gone.

One thing that may be confusing at first is `actionResponse.setRenderParameter(...)` method. Please note it's **Response** not **Request**!

#### What is the difference between `actionRequest.setAttribute(...)` and `actionResponse.setRenderParameter(...)`?

To answer this you need to understand how portlets work. Clients interact with portlets via portlet container. When they send action request to say portlet `P` they send it through the container. The container then

- sends **Action** request to the portlet `P`
- when `P` responds, sends **Render** requests to every portlet on that page, including `P`.

So `P` reseives two requests (one Action and one Render) from the container per single client request. The `actionResponse.setRenderParameter(...)` is used during action request to tell the containr to pass this parameter with the upcoming render request. That is essentialy the way to pass information from action to render phase.